# Привязки Python к JS и наоборот

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

Подскажите способы примирить языки Python3 и JS. 
Как можно реализовать вызов функции и передачу/получение параметров из одного языка в другой. Да и вообще обмен данными. Информации по этому поводу почти не нашел. Только zerorpc Python2, да и тот не устанавливается с помощью npm.

Comment: Как правило, они взаимодействуют на уровне клиент-сервера. Зачем их соединять напрямую?

Comment: @Александр, хочу написать десктопное приложение. А python в качестве backend'a.

Comment: вы хотели сказать, клиент-серверное? И клиент на электроне? Сформулируйте вопрос точнее

Comment: @Александр, клиент-серверное, да, но в данном случае клиент - это приложение Electron и код Python, а сервер = мост между ними, надеюсь так более конкретно

Answer (score 0):

Через ajax. 
Сайт http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ 
или использовать Splinter

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]